# Issue while clearing the cookie from html page

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a Home.aspx and a AboutUs.html page.When i click on the logout of my AboutUs page,my cookie is not cleared,when i came back to home page.
Below is the piece of code i m using to save & delete cookie

```
    var SaveCookie = function(zNameP, zValueP, IsPersistenceP)
    {
        IsPersistenceP = typeof IsPersistenceP !== 'undefined' ? IsPersistenceP : false;
        if (IsPersistenceP)
            SavePersistenceCookie(zNameP, zValueP);
        else
            document.cookie = zNameP + "=" + escape(zValueP);
    }
    function SavePersistenceCookie(zNameP, zValueP)
    {
        var ExpirationDate = new Date();
        ExpirationDate.setDate(ExpirationDate.getYear() + 1); //1 year
        var CookieValueL = escape(zValueP) + "; expires=" + ExpirationDate.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = zNameP + "=" + CookieValueL;
    }

    function DeleteCookie(zNameP)
    {
        document.cookie = zNameP + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';

    }
```

I m getting the cookie value in my home page after clearing it in aboutus.html.What am i doing wong?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting cookies can be interesting business sometimes due to the `path` portion of a cookie definition. If the `path` you set when expiring the cookie doesn't match that of the original cookie that was set then it won't clear it. You should add `path=/;` (see below) when deleting the cookie and double check the cookie `path` in your browser with Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools/Web Developer toolbar/whatever else.

Here's a JS function I have for deleting cookies. Notice how I specify `path=/;`:

```
function delCookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

If, for whatever reason, when the cookie was created it has a different value than `/` for its `path` then this function will not work. And, unfortunately, there is no way to access cookie information such as `domain` or `path` from JavaScript.

Comment: My Home Url is like this, from where i am saving cookie http://localhost/HDPortal/Home.aspx and my aboutus page where i m trying to clear cookie is http://localhost/HDPortal/HTML/AboutUs.htm

Comment: Then your path is possibly set to `/HDPortal`. You should try clearing your cookies and modifying the line that creates the cookie to explicitly set `path=/;`. You should also modify the line for deleting the cookie with the `path`.